# How to create a Spring bean from a static inner class constructor?

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, ioc-container

I am trying to use the Spring Framework IoC Container to create an instance of class
[ThreadPoolExecutor.CallerRunsPolicy](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.CallerRunsPolicy.html).  In Java, I'd do it this way...

```
import java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionHandler;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor;
...
RejectedExecutionHandler rejectedExecutionHandler = new ThreadPoolExecutor.CallerRunsPolicy();
```

But when I try to do the equivalent in Spring, it throws a *CannotLoadBeanClassException*.

```
<beans>
   <bean class="java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.CallerRunsPolicy"/>
</beans>
```

More generally: in a Spring ApplicationContext XML, how can you call a constructor of a static inner class?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think the reason it is not working is because Spring is not able to understand it as a static inner class.
Probably this can work:

```
<beans>
   <bean class="java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$CallerRunsPolicy"/>
</beans>
```

Comment: re-reading the original question and code sample I realize that drew isn't attempting to invoke a static method at all; just the constructor of a nested class. The `$` syntax is correct to use here, I've used this myself before.

Comment: That did work, thanks Ankit.  The Spring docs are here: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/reference/beans.html#beans-factory-class and it says "to configure a bean definition for a static inner class, you have to use the binary name of the inner class."

Answer (score 1):

Use [the `factory-method` attribute](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-class-static-factory-method):

> The following bean definition specifies that the bean will be created by calling a factory-method. The definition does not specify the type (class) of the returned object, only the class containing the factory method. In this example, the createInstance() method must be a static method.
>
> ```
> <bean id="clientService" class="examples.ClientService"
>   factory-method="createInstance"/>
> ```

Comment: I did attempt a few variations of "factory-method" but that does not work here because ThreadPoolExecutor.CallerRunsPolicy is a regular old Java constructor.  This is a static class.

Comment: The fact that CRP is a static nested class shouldn't matter here. While matt b's example for a static method is correct, you're not actually needing to invoke a static method here... just a plain ol' constructor. That being said, I'd be curious to see the rest of the details of the CannotLoadBeanClassException.