# Using static nested class as Spring bean

Tags: java, spring, inner-classes

How do I create an instance of a static nested class as a Spring bean in an XML configuration file?
For example:

```
package com.x.y;
public class A {
    public static class B {
    ...
    }
}
```

So that I have a Spring-managed bean of class `B`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to create a Spring bean from a static inner class constructor?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3818332/how-to-create-a-spring-bean-from-a-static-inner-class-constructor)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Using `A$B` syntax, which is how the classloader sees inner classes.  So assuming package `com.x.y`, then:

```
<bean id="myBean" class="com.x.y.A$B"/>
```

Comment: What about java annotation configuration alternative?